# BorderBrush not visible

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have 3 radio buttons. In usually state the `borderBrush` in the radioButton not visible, but it property not null. When I click on the radioButton, a center radiobutton will be visible, but the `borderBrush` is not.

Why is BorderBrush not visible?

```
<RadioButton Content="Low" 
             Tag="Low" 
             Grid.Row="1"
             BorderBrush="{StaticResource LowPrioritySolidColorBrush}"
             Checked="OnPriorityButtonChecked"
             FontSize="17"
             Visibility="Visible"
             Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
<RadioButton Grid.Column="1" 
             Margin="0,15,0,0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Content="Medium" 
             Tag="Medium" 
             Visibility="Visible"
             BorderBrush="{StaticResource MediumPrioritySolidColorBrush}"
             Checked="OnPriorityButtonChecked"
             FontSize="17"/>
<RadioButton Grid.Column="2" 
             Margin="20,15,0,0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Content="High"
             Tag="High" 
             Visibility="Visible"
             BorderBrush="{StaticResource HighPrioritySolidColorBrush}" 
             Checked="OnPriorityButtonChecked"
             FontSize="17"/>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you defined a border width?

Comment: It is possible that the border has the same color of the backgroud?

Comment: You mean BorderThickness?

Comment: Not possible. They have 3 different  colors.

Comment: You're going to have to post the XAML for your RadioButton style here as the problem almost certainly lies inside it.

Comment: In xaml they buttons visible and they have 3 different colors.

Comment: <Color x:Key="LowPriorityColor">#60BA66</Color>
<Color x:Key="MediumPriorityColor">#FFB900</Color>
 <Color x:Key="HighPriorityColor">#CE4949</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LowPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource LowPriorityColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource MediumPriorityColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighPriorityColor}"/>

Comment: My radioButtons have not style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default look of `RadioButtons` in UWP:

[image]

The outline of the "checkbox" is by default black and changes color to user's accent color when the button is checked. Also the dot inside is black. In your case however the `RadioButtons` look very different with a colorful dot inside and no outline, so there must be a custom `Style` being applied to them. Try to search your solution for `TargetType="RadioButton"` to find it. The `RadioButtons` don't have to have a `Style` directly, but it is enough for a `Style` targeting them without an `x:Key` to be defined.

When you apply a `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` to the default style, the result will look like this:

[image]

Which I guess is not what you want :-) . To achieve your goal, you will have to declare your own custom style, that will use the `BorderBrush` as the source color for the outline:

```
<Color x:Key="LowPriorityColor">#60BA66</Color>
<Color x:Key="MediumPriorityColor">#FFB900</Color>
<Color x:Key="HighPriorityColor">#CE4949</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LowPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource LowPriorityColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource MediumPriorityColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighPrioritySolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighPriorityColor}"/>
<Style x:Key="PriorityRadioStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,6,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse" Fill="{StaticResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFill}" Height="20" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="CheckOuterEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFill}" Height="20" Opacity="0" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="10"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The changes I have made from the default style are:

- Setting `OuterEllipse`'s `Stroke` to `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}`
- Setting `CheckOuterEllipse`'s `Stroke` to `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}`
- Setting `CheckGlyph`'s `Fill` to `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}`

And the result looks like:

[image]

This is however can still be improved by changing the default black color when the pointer is above the `RadioButton` and pressed. This can be done in each individual `VisualState` in the `Style`.

Of course, you must not forget to apply the style to your `RadioButtons`:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource PriorityRadioStyle}" Content="Low" 
                Tag="Low" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource LowPrioritySolidColorBrush}"
                FontSize="17"
                Visibility="Visible"
                Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource PriorityRadioStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                Margin="0,15,0,0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Medium" 
                Tag="Medium" 
                Visibility="Visible"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource MediumPrioritySolidColorBrush}"
                FontSize="17"/>
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource PriorityRadioStyle}" Grid.Column="2" 
                Margin="20,15,0,0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="High"
                Tag="High" 
                Visibility="Visible"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource HighPrioritySolidColorBrush}" 
                FontSize="17"/>
```

Comment: I have the same code. The last time my code was work. I did not change anything. But now it does not work.
Therefore I need you help.

Comment: A slight tangent: It's worth pointing out that while this is a pretty result, it's not great UI.  A color-blind person wouldn't be able to differentiate between the colors, so this would be lost on that person.  In general, when you want to differentiate by color, you should also try to differentiate by something else -- shape, icon, underline, etc.  That let's you get across the importance of each item to everyone.  That all said, +1 for the solution; well done. :)

Comment: @AlexcandraKhotko You must of course also apply the style to your radio buttons using `Style="{StaticResource PriorityRadioStyle}"`. I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: @AriRoth You are right, but in this case each radio button has a label as well, which does state the priority literally, so it should be good :-) .

Comment: @MartinZikmund True!  The text will cover it in this case.  I just wanted to point out that generally, simple colors are insufficient visual separators (except for shading -- darker/lighter shades of gray, for example, are usually ok).  Like I said, tangent. :)

Comment: I apply style in my Radio Buttons of course, but it is not work:( thanks to all to the help!

Comment: How does it not work? Something must be happening for sure? Does not the way they are displayed change at all?

Comment: I myself understand what it is correct code. But for some reason it stopped working for me.

Comment: I know, but how did it "stop" working. What behavior does it cause?

Comment: In one moment in my app BorderBrush became invisible. I do not understand why. Just now the behavior is the same: BorderBrush invisible.

Comment: Could you try creating an empty project just to try if it works there? If it does, we will have to try to track down the problem here